# why can error saving properties on pgadmin 4

Tags: heroku, pgadmin-4

I will create new server with database `pgadmi4` and use data from heroku.
I get this kind of problem...
[image]

thaks :)

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do on pgAdmin4 side, You need to configure your `AWS` instance to accept incoming connection from your IP address and update `pg_hba.conf` accordingly.